# Postgresql PG::ConnectionBad

Tags: postgresql, pg

I work on Windows. I try to use PostgreSQL database.

I have this error

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA9W7.png)

```
PG::ConnectionBad
�����: ���� "Anton" �� ����������

Rails.root: C:/Users/Anton/RubymineProjects/untitled
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
```

I can't find solution by searching because of those symbols in the error page.
Please help me find the right way to solve this problem

EDIT: Please find data from my **pg_hba.conf** file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to post the trace as text rather than an image as this will make it much easier to look through, To be honest however the trace doesn't appear to be giving much away. Have you confirmed that the database username, password, host and name are all correct ad that scripts in general can connect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry, because I am so lame. I am not sure how to confirm all that. I believe that I need to make some settings in my pg_hba.conf file, you can find it in my post.